# UPDATE com 2 Joins POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update, inner-join

gostaria pedir um help com um update no PosrgreSQL

Preciso atualizar o valor de uma coluna em uma tabela, mas que passe por condições de 2 tabelas.
Tentei o codigo:

```
update proced_conv set proced_conv.vl_unitario = (proced_conv.vl_unitario_bras * c.ajuste_porcent / proced_conv.fator_ajuste)
from proced_conv
   inner join convenio c on c.cd_convenio = proced_conv.cd_convenio 
   inner join proced_conv_det pcd on pcd.cd_proced_conv = proced_conv.cd_proced_conv
   where convenio.cd_convenio in (94, 146) and pcd.cd_proced = 28021609
```

Porem aparece o seguinte erro:

> ERROR:  table name "proced_conv" specified more than once SQL state:
> 4271

2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O PostgreSQL não utiliza este tipo de sintaxe. Tente:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT proced_conv.cd_convenio, proced_conv.vl_unitario_bras * c.ajuste_porcent / proced_conv.fator_ajuste AS val
    FROM proced_conv
       INNER JOIN convenio c on c.cd_convenio = proced_conv.cd_convenio 
    INNER JOIN proced_conv_det pcd on pcd.cd_proced_conv = proced_conv.cd_proced_conv
   WHERE convenio.cd_convenio in (94, 146) AND pcd.cd_proced = 28021609)
UPDATE proced_conv SET vl_unitario = t.val WHERE cd_convenio = t.cd_convenio;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!